# How to sort array according to date in x,y pair for highcharts in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this.

```
var arr=[[375122780000,3],[2375122780000,4],[4375122780000,5]];
```

These are some values for plotting graph in highcharts. Inside each pair,first value is for date in UTC format and  second for pressure value. How can I sort the pairs according to date in ascending order. That is, according to first value of each pair? I expect an output like this.

```
var arr=[[275122780000,4],[375122780000,3],[4375122780000,5]];
```

Comment: can you elaborate it with less higher values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well, it returns the wanted difference:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
function Comparator(a,b){
if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
return 0;
}

arr= arr.sort(Comparator);
```